# how to Handle Custom exception in spring boot rest filter methods?

Tags: spring-boot, authorization

I want to add a custom exception handler in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter filter methods.

I am using custom filters to get the authorization API key from the current request. then matching this API key with stored apikey, if API key is not matched want to display custom exception saying "invalid API key" or if API key not provided then "API key not found in authorization header".

**How to throw the custom notification as BadCredentialsException when API key not matched.**

**My SpringSecurityConfig class**

```
package com.nil.springjpa.security;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationManager;

import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;

import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter;

import com.nil.springjpa.exceptions.BadCredentialsException;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SpringSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationEntryPoint authEntryPoint;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("1st");

        /*
         * http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() .anyRequest().authenticated()
         * .and().httpBasic() .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
         */

        PreAuthTokenHeaderFilter filter = new PreAuthTokenHeaderFilter("Authorization");

        filter.setAuthenticationManager(new AuthenticationManager() {
            @Override
            public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {

                String principal = (String) authentication.getPrincipal();
                String authHeaderValue = "123xyz";
                System.out.println("5th" + principal);
                if (!authHeaderValue.equals(principal)) {
                    System.out.println("5th" + principal);
                    throw new BadCredentialsException("API Key not matched");
                }
                authentication.setAuthenticated(true);
                return authentication;
            }
        });

        http.csrf().disable().addFilter(filter)
                .addFilterBefore(new ExceptionTranslationFilter(authEntryPoint), filter.getClass()).authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().authenticated();

        /*
         * http.csrf().disable().authorizeRequests() .anyRequest().authenticated()
         * .and().httpBasic() .authenticationEntryPoint(authEntryPoint);
         */

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ControllerAdvice`.

```
@ControllerAdvice
@RequestMapping(produces = "application/json")
public class CentralExceptionHandler {

  @ExceptionHandler(CustomException.class)
  @ResponseBody
  protected void handleAccessDeniedException(CustomException ex, HttpServletResponse response) {

    response.setHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
    response.setStatus(status);
    response.getOutputStream().write("Something went wrong".getBytes());
  }    

}
```

`CustomException` needs to be a runtime exception and can be thrown from any place in your code.

Comment: thanks for the reply. I did but not working. i did the same but this particular method not invoked. i think ControllerAdvice will work for only rest controllers

Comment: Who is catching BadCredentialsException? If you let it propagate it will end up in the controller advice

Comment: I have similar case in one of my applications. Try creating a custom exception and throwing it. This way you can be sure nothing other than the controller advice is catching it.

Comment: controller advice is caching all the exceptions, its working fine for exceptions which invoked from controllers like Constraint violations. but not working when tried to throw from the filter authentication method.

Comment: shall i extend ResponseEntityExceptionHandler for CentralExceptionHandler class